# Tetration with 0 < #s < 1?

Tags: exponentiation, tetration, power-towers

When I try numbers between 0 and 1 on my calculator app n-calc on my phone .. I get rapid convergence when the numbers are close to 1 .. And alternating but slow convergence when numbers are close to zero .. The convergence is not 1 nor 0 but an irrational number between 0 and 1 .. is there a special name for the irr# i^i^i...? If not, may I?

Comment: It is not slow convergence when the input is close to zero.  You get to a point where the oscillations settle down to a constant altitude but do not die out anymore.  Tetration converges when the argument is conclusively between $\exp(-e)$ and $\exp(1/e)$.

Comment: wow thx .. and so beautifully unintuitive for #s > 1 .. O.O

Comment: can u help with my irrational density question?

Comment: Start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration.